# How to use group by to draw a bar chart with 2 columns in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I got the data like this

```
  color type  price     Y/N
1   R   A       H       Y
2   G   B       L       N
3   B   A       H       N
4   R   C       L       N
5   G   B       H       Y
6   R   A       H       Y
7   B   B       H       Y
```

I want to drow barchar with each column and group by Y/N column

something like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IksQm.png)

Sorry for the picture, hope you can understand it :)
Is this any easy way to draw the picture like this without to count number of each different type.
BTW, how to draw when it's not binary category, such as Y/N column has 4 different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for i in df.columns[:-1]:
    df.groupby([i,'Y/N'])[i].size().unstack().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I'm looking for. Just an addition, how to sort the index?

Comment: `df.sort_index()`